# Download an Image Windows phone 8

Tags: xaml, c#-4.0, windows-phone-8

I want to download an image from Internet, I could do it with Http Client. However, I want that when downloading hasn't completed yet, another Image be set to explain that "Image is being downloading". help me, please  :)

Comment: Post some codes showing what you have so far, then we can start from that

Answer (score 0):

Use BackgroundTransferService.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202955%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

The ProgressChanged and StatusChanged events should help you accomplish what you need.